# How to create logic for back button on ftl page for custom authentication flow pages in KeyCloak?

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, redhat, redhat-sso

How to do logic for back button on ftl page for custom authentication flow pages in Keycloak?
I am using spring boot framework for creating jar for KeyCloak.

I am trying to create custom authentication flow by KeyCloak. I have created custom login pages where user will use credential user-password for pre login page; for post login flow, I have created custom .ftl pages for authentication like user info validation, terms and conditions page. In that post login pages, I like to create back button on that pages to go previous steps on that authentication flow. How this logic we can create it? I do not see out of box feature from KeyCloak which provides back button functionalities.